# Physics of ballasting a transformer, does ballast have an equation?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, voltage

Does ballast have units? How much ballast do you need e.g. for limiting the current to a reasonable level for the plasma from an Mot? I got a Transformer out of the microwave and the internet recommends getting a second Transformer and I tried to look into why you would need that second one in line for ballast and it seems that it reduces the current for the Transformer that's actually producing the plasma. I also skimmed through the Wikipedia Paige on ballast and it seems there are different types of ballast resistive reactive inductive Etc so that makes me think they're probably aren't specific units per say... my problem is I would like to figure out how to construct an ballast rather than acquiring the second Transformer because I suspect that that is excessive and I don't want to limit all of the current. In fact I suspect that all you would need is a large extension cord coiled up on like a two by four. Is that insane, and how can I do some calculations? What's the physics here?

Comment: Perhaps better suited to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ ; MOTs have a number of properties (such as very high core magnetization) that make it risky to run them without a large amount of current limiting.

Answer (score 0):

> Does ballast have units?

The ballast provides impedance to a current, so it is measured in ohms.

> In fact I suspect that all you would need is a large extension cord
>   coiled up on like a two by four. Is that insane, and how can I do some
>   calculations? What's the physics here?

This would be an inductive ballast. The magnitude of the impedance of an inductor is $wL=2\pi fL$, where $f$ is AC frequency and $L$ is the inductance. Assuming AC frequency of $50-60$Hz and the inductance of a coil, made out of an extension cord, on the order of few $\mu H$, the impedance would be a fraction of an ohm, clearly not adequate for the task.

Beyond that I cannot recommend anything, but I would note that this setup, even with an adequate ballast, is very dangerous and can easily kill.